# React Google Maps - get position of marker on DragEnd

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, draggable

I'm using [@react-google-maps/api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-google-maps/api)  to make my google map in react.

```
  <GoogleMap
      onLoad={onMapLoad}
      options={{
        draggable: true,
        scrollwheel: false,
        keyboardShortcuts: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        fullscreenControl: false,
        zoomControl: true,
        streetViewControl: false,
      zoom={17}
      center={{
        //get user location
        lat: -3.745,
        lng: -38.523,
      }}
    ></GoogleMap>
```

I'm trying to get the lat/lng values of the marker after i drag it using the following

```
const onMapLoad = map => {
  let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: markerPosition,
  map: map,
  draggable: true,
})
marker.addListener('dragend', handleDragEnd)
}


const handleDragEnd = e => {
    console.log(e.latLng)
  }
```

The marker loads onto the map correctly, however when I try to drag the console log just returns null for both lat/lng values. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```js
marker.addListener('dragend', function (e) {
  console.log(this.getPosition().toJSON()); // this === marker
})
```

see https://jsfiddle.net/4s6xcy2o/1/

Note: your usage of the arrow function will change `this`

Comment: Thank you very much, Now got it working correctly